# Pulumi file archive - no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, deployment, aws-lambda, pulumi

I feel like I'm making a silly mistake here, but Pulumi cannot seem to see the file I'm using to [create an asset][1] with. The files are right beside each other in the directory. Here is the file structure:

```
-- /resources
    -- function.js
    -- lambda.ts
```

Pretty simple. Here is the file where we try and use the Javascript file as an asset for the Lambda we are creating:

```
// lambda.ts

import * as pulumi from '@pulumi/pulumi';
import * as aws from '@pulumi/aws';

const file = new pulumi.asset.FileAsset('./function.js');
console.log('file', file);

export const exampleFunction = new aws.lambda.Function('exampleFunction', {
  role: role.arn,
  runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
  code: file,
});
```

I've written a script to run my Pulumi commands. I also `pwd` and `ls` the file directory to confirm that the file is there.

```
# deploy.sh

#!/bin/sh

ls resources
pulumi preview
```

Output/error:

> - ls resources -- function.js     lambda.ts
> - pulumi preview --
>   Error: failed to register new resource exampleFunction [aws:lambda/function:Function]: 2 UNKNOWN: failed to compute archive hash: couldn't read archive path './function.js': stat ./function.js: no such file or directory

Kinda lost on this one. The file is right there.

Edit:

I've realized that the file path **must be relative to where the `Pulumi.yaml` file is located**, so one directory above `/resources` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `FileAsset` and not `FileArchive`, as `FileArchive` is for tar.gz and related archive files: https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/assets-archives/

At least I think that's what's going on. If that's true then the error message is not great as it doesn't tell you what the actual problem is.

Comment: oh i forgot to change it as i was using a build directory before. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Where is `deploy.sh` or more specifically, `pulumi preview` being run?
Is it being run in the "resources" folder, or someplace else - e.g. in the folder above?
If it's not being run from the resources folder, then that's likely the issue and so you need to provide the path to function.js from where pulumi is being run.